# How I can add Input text and show in li that created by map in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react.js, I would like to create a contact manager as a result, I created an input text that would like to add contacts, also I created a list with a map and class component. When I click on the button (add contact), I would like this name instead of show in the console to add to the list below created with the map(users) and show it on the list that was created with the map. could you please help me with how I can show add a contact in the list?

```js
class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      AddContact: "",
      users: [
        { name: "James Smith", href: "" },
        { name: "Thomas Anderson", href: "" },
        { name: "Bruce Wayne", href: "" },
      ],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  // Event For Input
  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  // Event For Submit
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="ftco-section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-5">
              <div className="login-wrap p-4 p-md-5">
                <div className="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <span className="fas fa-user"></span>
                </div>
                <h3 className="text-center mb-4">Contact Manager</h3>
                <form className="login-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control rounded-left"
                      placeholder="Add New Contact"
                      name="AddContact"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      required
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-secondary rounded submit p-2 px-4"
                    >
                      Add Contact
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ul className="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          {this.state.users && this.state.users.lenght ? this.state.users : []}

          {this.state.users.map((user) => (
            <li>
              <a href={user.href}>{user.name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Contact />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, (1) create a new user row based on the value of `AddContact`, (2) copy the old `users` array (this will trigger a state update because you're creating a new object) and (3) add the new user to the freshly created array. Add the following lines at the end of `handleSubmit`:

```
const newUser = { name: this.state.AddContact, href: "" };
this.setState({ users: [...this.state.users, newUser] });
```

---

Full code

```js
class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      AddContact: "",
      users: [
        { name: "James Smith", href: "" },
        { name: "Thomas Anderson", href: "" },
        { name: "Bruce Wayne", href: "" },
      ],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  // Event For Input
  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  // Event For Submit
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log(this.state);
    const newUser = { name: this.state.AddContact, href: "" };
    this.setState({ users: [...this.state.users, newUser] });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="ftco-section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-5">
              <div className="login-wrap p-4 p-md-5">
                <div className="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <span className="fas fa-user"></span>
                </div>
                <h3 className="text-center mb-4">Contact Manager</h3>
                <form className="login-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control rounded-left"
                      placeholder="Add New Contact"
                      name="AddContact"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      required
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-secondary rounded submit p-2 px-4"
                    >
                      Add Contact
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ul className="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          {this.state.users && this.state.users.lenght ? this.state.users : []}

          {this.state.users.map((user) => (
            <li>
              <a href={user.href}>{user.name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Contact />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first clone your users then push new user and finally update main state, here is all you should add in your code

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //clone
    const users=[...this.state.users];

    //push new user
    users.push({name:this.state.AddContact,href:''})

    //update state
    this.setState({users})
  }
```